# Detect sheet name in excel that starts with "Feu"

Tags: excel, vba

IN the code i need to rename a sheet that starts with "Feu" into a specific name called "Pivot". The problem is that the I know the start will be "Feuill" and at the end it would "Feuill1" or any number. Do you guys have any ideas how i should proceed below is my code to make it detact any shee name with that start with "Feu" rename into  "Pivot" thanks

```
Sheets("Feuil15").Select
Sheets("Feuil15").Name = "PivotAutres"
```

Comment: What if all of them, or almost all have names starting with "Feu"? This means Sheet in French and it is very probable that this is reality. Does the workbook in discussion have only one single such worksheet? You cannot rename more then one sheet with the same string name. Being it "PivotAutres" or something else. Or would you like to find the first one, naming it as you want and then exiting the iteration?

Answer (score 1):

Loop through all sheets and compare the sheet name with `Like "Feu*"`:

```
Dim Sh As Variant
For Each Sh in ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If Sh.Name Like "Feu*" Then
        ' sheet name starts with Feu
    End If
Next Sh
```